# Passing data to REST service: JSON or URL query parameters?

Tags: php, angular, http

A common way of passing parameters to a RESTful web service is in the URL:

```
website.com/action.php?table=myTable&key=myKey&values=myValues
```

Another way would be with JSON:

```
{
  "data": 
     [
       {
         "parameters": {"table":"myTable", "key":"myKey", "values":"myValues"} 
       },
       {
         "content": {"data1":"dataVal1","data2":"dataVal2"} 
       }
     ]
}
```

What would be the pros and cons of these two methods:

- When would I use one over the other
- Benefits of each one
- Weaknesses
- Performance differences

Comment: BTW a "query parameter" [is by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the URL.

Comment: there are quite a few frameworks that use JSON for API communication;  it's not uncommon.  This feels less like a question and more like a rant, especially given you try to justify your point of view with pros and cons that feel out of place in a question body.

Comment: @msanford interesting. You knew what I meant, but thanks for the correction. Then again, maybe the definition is such due to a standard way of passing parameters through the URL? I don't know, just a thought.

Comment: @Claies always happy to learn the proper way of posting on a site that provides endless help. I'll take the pros/cons out.

Comment: _"The common way..."_ I would say that this is incorrect and should be worded, "***A*** common way..." Passing via JSON is at least as common, and probably more so for POST requests.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Very well, I've made the suggested change. To the comment of it being just as common, maybe that's true I'm not questioning the knowledge of those that say so. I'm saying that many google searches still seem to render more available content on the URL method.

Comment: @slanden Of course, I just wanted to highlight the use of specific terminology. :)

Comment: It doesn't merit a full answer, a rule of thumb for me is "should this be shareable?" If so: query params, even if it's long; a Google Maps URL being a good example.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values using REST, you must use a `GET` request. There are no request bodies with `GET` requests, so your only option is the url.

When changing values in REST service, you typically use the `PUT` request. This `PUT` request should contain the new resource state in it's body.

So it's not an either/or matter. Where you place certain request parameters depends on what kind of operation you are doing, and what the meaning of the parameter is.